# Compare string within an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, string

i am new. Hope someone can help me.I want to compare a string from user input  with a course title variable which is also a string type.The "course title" variable it's part of the state of a number of objects that are inserted in an array of objects.

Here is the code:

```
    if (selection.equals("yes")){
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("Enter the day of exam you want to search: ");
        int search= ScannerUtility.readInt();
        int i = 0;

line 43    while( i<a.length && search.equals(a[i].getCourseTitle()) ){
           i++;
           {
```

here the console error:

```
line   43: 

error: int cannot be dereferenced while( i<a.length && search.equals(a[i].getCourseTitle() ) ){
```

---

```
//Here is all the classes
```

I am italian, thus sorry if i don't translate properly.BTW here is the ManagementExams Class:

```
import java.util.*;
    public class ManagementExams{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("MANAGEMENT EXAMS");
            System.out.print("Indicate how many exams do you want to insert: ");
            int dim = ScannerUtility.readInt();
            int nexams = 1;
            Exam [] a = new Exam[dim];
                for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
                    System.out.print("Insert the name of the exam " + nexams +":");
                    String coursetitle = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Insert the day of the exam: ");
                    int day = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                    System.out.print("Insert the month of the exam: ");
                    String month = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Insert the year of the exam: ");
                    int year = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                    System.out.print("Insert the hour of the exam: ");
                    int hourexam = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                    Exam b = new Exam(coursetitle,day,month,year,hourexam);
                    a[i] = b;
                    nexams++;
                }
                    System.out.print("The number of exams inserted are': " + (nexams-1)+ "\n\n");
                    System.out.println("Print Exams: \n");
                        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                            System.out.println(a[i]);


                            System.out.print("Do you want to change the day of certain exams?: ");

                            String selection = sc.nextLine();

                                if (selection.equals("yes")){
                                    System.out.print("");
                                    System.out.print("Insert the name of the exam you want to search: ");
                                    String search= ScannerUtility.readString();
                                    int i = 0;

                                        while( i<a.length && search.equals(a[i].getCourseTitle()) )
                                            i++;


                                            if(i<a.length){
                                                System.out.println("I found the following exam: \n" + a[i]);
                                                System.out.print("Change the day: ");
                                                int day= ScannerUtility.readInt();
                                                a[i].setDay(day);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                System.out.println("No exam was found ");
                                                System.exit(0);
                                            }

                                }

                                else if(selection.equals("no"))
                                    System.exit(0);

                                for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                                System.out.print("Mold the update data of the exams: \n" + a[i] +"\n");
        }
    }
```

Here the class Exam:

```
public class Exam{

    private String coursetitle;
    private int day;
    private String month;
    private int year;
    private int hourexam;


    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public Exam(String coursetitle,int day,String month,int year,int hourexam){
        this.coursetitle=coursetitle;
        this.day=day;
        this.month=month;
        this.year=year;
        this.hourexam=hourexam;
    }




    //SET METHODS
    public void setCourseTitle(String a){
        this.coursetitle=a;
    }
    public void setDay(int a){
        this.day=a;
    }

    public void setMonth(String a){
        this.month=a;
    }

    public void setYear(int a){
        this.year=a;
    }

    public void setHourExam(int a){
            this.hourexam=a;
    }

    //GET METHODS
    public String getCourseTitle(){
        return this.coursetitle;
    }
    public int getDay(){
        return this.day;
    }
    public String getMonth(){
        return this.month;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return this.year;
    }
    public int getHourExam(){
        return this.hourexam;
    }

    //TOSTRING

    public String toString(){
        return coursetitle +"\n" + day + "\n" + month + "\n" + year +"\n" + hourexam;
    }


}
```

Both class build and compile correctly,but when i create an exam with the coursetitle like "math" and then i try to search it,with the string input "math" the program jump to the println method "no exam was found".

Comment: Can we see the definition of `a`?

Comment: `search` is a primitive type, you can't access to fields or methods..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`search` is an `int` which cannot be dereferenced (i.e. you cannot use `.` with it).  It seems like using `==` may work if it is an integer, but perhaps getCourseTitle returns a string.  In that case, convert the integer to a string.

```
while (i < a.length && Integer.toString(search).equals // etc.
```

Comment: Well spotted. It might be the the problem is some semantic bug as does not makes much sense to compare "exam days" with "course titles" We need the full code @ggianino

Comment: i have updated the first post ;)..one thing what is that "Integer" that you used in the example?

Comment: @ggianino Integer is the int wrapper class java.lang.Integer. He is using it to access the static method toString therein implemented. ("" + search).equals would be as effective.

Comment: Why should i convert an int value to a string value and viceversa? The problem it's located here: while( i<a.length && search.equals(a[i].getCourseTitle()) ).How can i compare the string value of user input with the coursetitle var in the Exam object?

Comment: @ggianino Why are you using `ScannerUtility.readInt` then?  That reads in an int...

Comment: I modified the code in the update ;)                                     String search= ScannerUtility.readString();

Answer (score 0):

//PROBLEM SOLVED ;)

```
import java.util.*;
public class ManagementExams{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("MANAGEMENT EXAMS \n");
        System.out.print("Indicate how many exams do you want to insert: ");
        int dim = ScannerUtility.readInt();
        int nexams = 1;
        Exam [] a = new Exam[dim];
            for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Insert the name of the exam " + nexams +":");
                String coursetitle = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Insert the day of the exam: ");
                int day = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                System.out.print("Insert the month of the exam: ");
                String month = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Insert the year of the exam: ");
                int year = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                System.out.print("Insert the hour of the exam: ");
                int hourexam = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                Exam b = new Exam(coursetitle,day,month,year,hourexam);
                a[i] = b;
                nexams++;
            }
                System.out.print("The number of exams inserted are: " + (nexams-1)+ "\n\n");
                System.out.println("Print Exams: \n");
                    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
                        System.out.println(a[i].toString());
                    }

                        System.out.print("Do you want to change the day of certain exams?: ");

                        String selection = sc.nextLine();
                            if (selection.equals("yes")){
                                System.out.print("");
                                System.out.print("Insert the name of the exam you want to search: ");
                                String search = ScannerUtility.readString();
                                boolean var = false;

                                    for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){

                                        if(search.equals(a[i].getCourseTitle()) ){
                                            var = true;
                                            System.out.println("I found the following exam: \n" + a[i].toString() );
                                            System.out.print("Change the day: ");
                                            int newday = ScannerUtility.readInt();
                                            a[i].setDay(newday);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if(var == false ){
                                        System.out.println("No exam was found ");
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }

                                    System.out.println("");
                                    for(int j=0; j < a.length; j++){
                                        System.out.println("Exams updated: \n" + a[j].toString() + "\n");
                                    }

                                    System.exit(0);

                            }else if(selection.equals("no")){
                                System.exit(0);
                            }


    }
}
```